# Saving dataset attributes in JSON File with the responce of the form (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to build a JSON file where I store all the answers from a Form. Some of the inputs are having an extra **dataset attribute (data-tag)**. When I'm saving the Form I want to extract all these 'tags' in the JSON file as keys and as value the input's value. I've tried to do that by adding references to these inputs and taking the name of the tag with $refs.

I am getting an error:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

I am trying currently to store the 'tags' in a separate Array and then append this to the Form Output.

Not sure if this is the right solution, but I couldn't think of anything else, so feel free if you have any other idea.

- Vue.js version: 2.6
- vuetify.js version: 2.3

Form inputs:

```
<v-text-field label="ICD" id="pos_t_1" name="pos_t_1" ref="icd" data-tag="icd_tag" v- 
  model="textfield" hide-details="auto" />

<v-radio-group v-model="radio" hide-details="auto" row>
  <v-radio
    v-for="radio in group"
    ref="radioGroup"
    :key="radio.id"
    :id="radio.id"
    :name="radio.id"
    color="primary"
    :data-tag="radio.tag"
    :label="radio.text"
    :value="radio.text"
  >
 </v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

Script:

```
export default Vue.extend({
name: 'Test',
data: function () {
    return {
        tags: [],
        radio: '',
        group: [
            {id: 'pos_r_2', text: 'Radio 1', tag: 'radio_tag_2'},
            {id: 'pos_r_3', text: 'Radio 2', tag: 'radio_tag_3'},
            {id: 'pos_r_4', text: 'Radio 3', tag: 'radio_tag_4'},
            {id: 'pos_r_5', text: 'Radio 4', tag: 'radio_tag_5'},
        ],
    }
},
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
        Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach((value) => {
           const refs = this.$refs[value];
           if (Array.isArray(refs)) {
               for (let i = 0; i <= this.$refs[value].length; i++) {
                   let key = this.$refs[value][i].$attrs['data-tag']
                   this.tags[key].push(this.radio)
               }
           } else {
               let key = this.$refs[value].$attrs['data-tag']
               this.tags[key].push(this.textfield)
           }
        })
    }
}
})
```

Form's JSON structure:

```
  [{
     "pos_t_1":"Test",
     "pos_r_2":"",
     "pos_r_3":"Radio 3",
     "pos_r_4":"",
     "pos_r_5":"",
  }],
```

The JSON structure I want:

```
  [{
     "pos_t_1":"Test",
     "icd_tag":"Test",
     "pos_r_2":"",
     "radio_tag_2":"",
     "pos_r_3":"Radio 3",
     "radio_tag_3":"Radio 3",
     "pos_r_4":"",
     "radio_tag_4":"",
     "pos_r_5":"",
     "radio_tag_5":"",
  }],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to push to an empty array you cannot push to a specified key as it does not exist.

So when you declare `tags = []` and then try to push `tags[key].push(value)` tags[key] is undefined so push method is not available

Instead you change the onSubmit method as below

```js
onSubmit() {
        Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach((value) => {
           const refs = this.$refs[value];
           if (Array.isArray(refs)) {
               for (let i = 0; i <= this.$refs[value].length; i++) {
                   let key = this.$refs[value][i].$attrs['data-tag']
                   this.tags[key] = this.radio
               }
           } else {
               let key = this.$refs[value].$attrs['data-tag']
               this.tags[key] = this.textfield
           }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this.tags[key] = this.textfield worked for the text field. 
I am having another Problem for the radios. When I try this.tags[key] = this.radio inside the for loop, all the radio tags get the same value from the selected radio, but I need the value to be only for the selected tag from the selected radio and the rest of the tags has to be empty. Do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: I don't know about vuetify. But you can do some conditional like `this.refs[i]['data-tag'] === 'radio.tag' && this.$refs[i].checked){ this.tags[key] = this.radio} else { this.tags[key] = ''}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Donkarnash I did it like that:

```
            Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach((value) => {
            const refs = this.$refs[value];
            if (Array.isArray(refs)) {
                for (let i = 0; i < refs.length; i++) {
                    let key = refs[i].$attrs['data-tag']
                    if (refs[i].isActive === true) {
                        this.tags[key] = this.radio
                    }
                    else {
                        this.tags[key] = ''
                    }
                }
            } else {
                let key = refs.$attrs['data-tag']
                this.tags[key] = this.textfield
            }
        })
```

Maybe this will help also someone else.